# I cannot install curl in my debian linux terminal

Tags: curl, terminal

When I run

```
    sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl
```

My terminal couldn't connect to packages.bosslinux.in

and even I cannot go to the packages.bosslinux.in web
please help me!!!!!

Comment: What's your stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry, but  StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  or [unix.se] , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.